# Changing balls direction in Pong

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Pong game to get started with game-developement but
I've run into a problem that i can't figure out.

When trying to change the balls direction it doesn't change. This is the relevant code:

```
function moveBall(){
    this.speed = 2.5;
    this.direction = 2;
    if(this.direction == 1){
        ball.X +=this.speed;
    }
    else if(this.direction == 2){
        ball.X -=this.speed;
    }
}

function collision(){
    if(ball.X == 500){
        moveBall.direction = 2;
    }
    if(ball.X == 300){
        moveBall.direction = 1;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work? I've tried many different ways, and none of them seem to work.
The `moveBall.direction` changes though, since it alerts the new direction once it reaches the defined `ball.X` position.

If someone could help me I would deeply appreciate it.
I've included a JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/y4wp3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** I would remove your direction variable because it can be included as part of the speed variable: negative speed values move left and positive speed values move right. This allows you to remove the if statements in the `moveBall` function and reduce it to a line or two

**2)** `direction` (if you keep it) and `speed` should be set outside of the move function, this will fix your problem. Every time you go to move your ball, it's resetting the `speed` and the `direction` back to their original values.

**3)** Using `==` to compare the position against an exact point can be dangerous, it is better to always use `>=` or `<=` depending on the case. But I won't be too hard on you because I'm pretty sure that's just for testing.

I don't really want to give you the codez, even though I did fix it, because learning how to fix these things is all part of the learning process :)

Comment: Excellent! The ball now bounces back and forth and with so much less code. Thank you very much. And yes, the == signs were just for testing, real collisions will require more complex code. :)

Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to handle this would be to omit the direction variable and just deal with xspeed and yspeed.  This is how I handle reversing directions.

```
Ball = {
    pos: {x: 2, y: 2},
    size: {x: 8, y: 8},
    speed: {x: 2, y: 2},
    update: function() {
        if (this.pos.x < 0 || (this.pos.x + this.size.x) > canvas.width) this.speed.x *= -1;
        if (this.pos.y < 0 || (this.pos.y + this.size.y) > canvas.height) this.speed.y *= -1;
        this.pos.x += this.speed.x * deltaTime;
        this.pos.y += this.speed.y * deltaTime;
    }
}
```

If you require the direction variable, you can keep track of the previous x and y position and do a trace from that to the new position.

**Edit**:  Keep in mind the code assumes the Ball is 8px by 8px and is drawn from top-left rather than the center.  It would be easy to add an offset and have this handled for you.

Comment: This is a rather old question, allthough I like the way you handle the updating, and will try to implement it into my code (right now the game is playable but the code isn't that good looking). I might go back and update it.

Comment: It's important to deal with axis separately.  There was a thread about it recently.

Comment: I don't know what "deal with axis" means, but the code I posted here has been changed long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

why did you put `this.direction = 2;` in second line of `moveBall` function? just remove it!

Comment: read the lines directly below and it will become clear. it is to define right or left. but removed it since previous poster came with a much better solution

Comment: I know about that, but just read your code! every time ball move first you set direction to 2 which means the ball will move left, and then you check if value of direction is 2 move it toward left. that's why I'm asking you put such an statement there.